# after calling jQuery.i18n library I am getting Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function in my login method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, internationalization

I am using  jQuery.i18n to bundle my project and I am calling it like

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <% String locale =request.getSession().getAttribute("language").toString();%>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadBundles1('<%=locale.toLowerCase()%>');
    });

    function loadBundles1(lang11) {
        jQuery.i18n.properties({
         //   language:lang
        });
    }

</script>
```

and it is working correctly ... but the problem is when I am trying to make login I am getting this error

Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function when I click login button, the javascript login function is not even called

my form

```
<form name="headerLoginForm" class="loginForm" method="post"
                                  action="JavaScript:login('headerLoginForm','${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login/login');">
```

my button

```
<button id="loginButton2" type="submit" class="app-button ladda-button"
                                            data-style="expand-right"
                                            name="Submit">
                                        <span class="ladda-label"><fmt:message key="login" /></span>
                                    </button>
```

Note : when I comment out jQuery.i18n code the login is working correctly

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error now by changing the method name from login to login1 but I don't know what was the error ?!

so the code

`action="JavaScript:login` 
 changed to

```
action="JavaScript:login1
```